# GraphDB 8.10 Geosparql geof:nearby how to

Tags: function, sparql, querying, graphdb, geosparql

I am quite new to sparql and geosparql and I am using `GraphDB 8.10` and have already enabled `geosparql` plugin by executing this in `SPARQL` interface

```
PREFIX : <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/geosparql#>

INSERT DATA {
  _:s :enabled "true" .
}
```

I have used `protege` to create an ontology and let's say I have 3 Points of type `POINT` under `feature` class with data type `asWkt Literal`. 1 one point is attached to a museum and other 2 are just points nearby.

What I am trying to do is which is the correct syntax to use the `geof:nearby` function to set a radius to check and retrieve one of those 2 points.

My query is as follows:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
prefix geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
prefix unit: <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#>
prefix sf: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#>
prefix test24: <http://www.semanticweb.org/evangelos/ontologies/2019/2/untitled-ontology-2#>

SELECT ?geom ?feature
WHERE{
    ?f a test24:GPSPoint ;
       rdfs:label ?feature ;
       geo:hasGeometry ?geom.
    ?geom geof:nearby (test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou 1 unit:Kilometer)
}
```

Keep in mind that test24:GPSPoint is equivalent class to sf:Point

Although I ve seen the triples in the graph overview, the particular query is not wrong but it returns nothing when I want to return a particular point of the two aforementioned.

Comment: from where do you have this `nearby` function? I'm sure the first argument has to be either some geo literal or lat and long values.

Comment: ok, the syntax is either `<Geometry> geof:nearby (<Geometry> <Number of units> <Unit>)` or `<Geometry> geof:nearby (LAT LONG <Number of units> <Unit>)`. So you have to get the geometry object for `test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou` first.

Comment: from ontotext geo-spatial extensions provided by GraphDB

Comment: I edited my previous comment, this should answer your question and solve the issue. You can't just use an arbitrary RDF resource as first argument, you have to get the geometry object of it and use this

Comment: how do I get the geometry object for test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou ? can you please provide how the query should be or how do I get what you suggested in there ? Post a normal answer to test it and accept it as solution

Comment: well, I don't know your data...so I don't know what `test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou` is. But if it is some object that has some geographic data, then it should be `test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou geo:hasGeometry ?geom2. ?geom geof:nearby (?geom2 1 unit:Kilometer)` - or not? I think you get the idea.

Comment: unless `test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou` is a geometry object, then your query should already work. So, is it of type `geo:Geometry` or not is the question here. Only you can check this with `ask {test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou rdf:type geo:Geometry}`

Comment: it answered me with a big red NO

Comment: MouseiMetaksisSoufliou is an instance of Type museum which is a subclass of feature of subclass spatial object class from geosparql straight import. This instance has a property "hasGPSCoordinates" to the instance MMSPoint which is of type "Point" and has a data type property "asWKT" with POINT(-77.03524 38.889468)

Comment: ah, ok, each Point is in fact a Geometry, so all we have to do is getting this geometry object and use it in the function. So `test24:MouseioMetaksisSoufliou hasGPSCoordinates ?geom2. geof:nearby (?geom2 1 unit:Kilometer)` should do the trick. Can you try it? (don't forget to use the correct prefix for the property `hasGPSCoordinates)

Comment: Your first line indeed retrieves the instance MMSPoint which is of type Point/GPSPoint, but the second line you proposed geof:nearby... the compiler says the line is invalid for some reason

Comment: well, indeed it has to be `?geom geof:nearby (?geom2 1 unit:Kilometer)` for the second line